# Minimizing the execution time in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have a document called `login`. the document contains the following:

- username
- password
- gender

I have another document called `history` which contains the following:

- username
- time

I the history document the `username` is referenced to  `login` document. 
Using the `time` field I'll get the details from the history document with the following query.

```
usersByHistory=models.history.objects(time=searchObj.time)
```

using the above result I'll get the user's information using the following code:

```
list=[]    
for user in usersByHistory :
   name = user.user_name.user_name
   usersList = login_info.objects(user_name=name)
   list.append(usersList)
```

By executing the above code the execution time is very high, I want to  avoid this for loop in the code and replace it with mongoengine query so as to minimize the execution time. someone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do an `in` query and provide the array of users: http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#query-operators

Heres an example using `scalar` because we only need a list of user_names.

```
users_by_history = History.objects(time=searchObj.time).scalar('user_name')
LoginInfo.objects(user_name__in=users_by_history)
```

*I have updated the class names and variable names to conform to pep8